# Taking average of non zero columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a matrix-

```
matrix=[[0,0,1,1],[1,2,0,1],[9,0,1,0],[1,1,2,0]]
```

I want to take column wise average but I only want to include the non zero values in the column.
I used the following-

```
array= [float(sum(col))/len(col)  for col in zip(*matrix)]
```

but it displays 2.75 in the first column whereas it should be 1+9+1/3=3.6

Comment: Shouldn't the first column be `(1 + 9 + 1) / 3 = 3.667`? Also, do you want a numpy solution or a pandas solution (you have tagged both)?

Comment: Convert to an array and simply do `matrix.sum(0)/(matrix!=0).sum(0).astype(float)`.

Comment: @Divakar - hmmm, post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
import numy as np
matrix=np.array([[0,0,1,1],[1,2,0,1],[9,0,1,0],[1,1,2,0]])
array=[np.mean(col[col!=0]) for col in matrix.T]
#array is: [3.6666666666666665, 1.5, 1.3333333333333333, 1.0]
```

Comment: I think this is taking row-wise mean, transposing the matrix: `array=[np.mean(col[col>0]) for col in np.transpose(matrix)]` will make it a column-wise mean.

Comment: Also, it should be `col != 0` per the OP's wording.  There are no negative numbers in the sample data, but the wording says "I only want to include the non zero values in the column".

Answer (score 0):

A direct substitution to your method will be, should be the fastest among others (for problem of this size) as well:

```
>>> array= [float(sum(col))/sum(map(bool,col))  for col in zip(*matrix)]
>>> array
[3.6666666666666665, 1.5, 1.3333333333333333, 1.0]
```

**EDIT:**

A more robust method, tackles columns with all zero:

```
>>> matrix=[[0,0,1,0],[1,2,0,0],[9,0,1,0],[1,1,2,0]]
>>> array= [float(sum(col))/sum(map(bool,col)) if sum(map(bool,col))>0 else 0 for col in zip(*matrix)]
>>> array
[3.6666666666666665, 1.5, 1.3333333333333333, 0]
```

Comment: what if some columns are entirely zero?

Comment: Edited the answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `pd.DataFrame().mask`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
df.mask(df.eq(0)).mean()
```

Output:

```
0    3.666667
1    1.500000
2    1.333333
3    1.000000
dtype: float64
```